# Why not "nuclear weapon program," but "nuclear weapons program"?

Tags: grammar

We normally encounter the expression, "North Korea's nuclear weapons program." But why not "~ nuclear weapon program"? Is that governed by a grammar rule?

Answer (score 2):

A "nuclear weapons program" is one that makes nuclear *weapons*, plural.  If it was just designed to build one bomb, then the sentence would have a different structure:

> [The Manhattan Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project) was a World War II research and development program whose purpose was to build **an atom bomb**.

Although, in actuality the Manhattan project ended up building several atom bombs, this sentence focuses on the fact that no one had previously built an atom bomb, and so the project's main goal was to build the *first* one.

You can also talk about a country's *chemical* or *biological weapons* program, or (on a less military note) its *national parks* program, its *clean lakes* program, its *safe neighborhoods* program, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many kinds of nuclear weapons (bombs, missiles, winged rockets etc.), so term "nuclear weapon**s** program" is fully correct.

Comment: Or rather that it's a program to make nuclear **weapons** (plural), even if all use the same delivery system.

Comment: @Andrew, yes, you're right, this is also a sufficient reason for plural.